# Power BI plot text events with a line chart

Tags: powerbi

I am trying to do a simple thing. I have a line chart with a date column for X-axis and a number column for Y-axis. What I want to do is add some visualization for events, like a vertical line with a label. I have a table of events which has two columns, date and events as text.

For some reason this seems really difficult to achieve in Power Bi. Is there a way to use an R script or something? Custom visualization?

[image: Example]

Answer (score 1):

The [Analytics tab in the Visualizations pane](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/transform-model/desktop-analytics-pane) can do exactly this.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Can you use this to link a table? Because I have a date table of events. With your solution I would have to manually write the events, no?

Comment: You have to do this by hand at the moment. I imagine they'll eventually make it dynamic but don't hold your breath.